# Eigenvalue of a matrix where a row is proportional to a versor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a real square matrix $A = \{a_{i,j}\} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. Suppose that $A$ has a row which entries are $0$, except for the element on the diagonal, i.e. the $i$-th row of $A$ is proportional to the versor $\bf{e}_i$.

Is it always true that at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to $a_{i,i}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true  that at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to $a_{ii}$.

Let ${\bf e}_i$ be the column vector with all entries $0$ with the exception of the $i$-th entry which is $1$.

Since the $i$-th row of $A$ has all entries 0 with the exception for the element on the main diagonal, it follows that ${\bf e}_i^T A=a_{ii}{\bf e}^T_i$ which is equivalent to
$$A^T{\bf e}_i=a_{ii}{\bf e}_i.$$
Hence $a_{ii}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$ (with eigenvector ${\bf e}_i$).
and
$$0=\det(A^{T} - a_{ii} I) = \det((A - a_{ii} I)^{T})  = \det (A - a_{ii}  I).$$
Therefore $a_{ii}$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @the_candyman Any further doubt?

Comment: Then, your claim is "If both the $i$-th row and the $i$-th column of $A$ are equal to $a_{ii}{\bf e_i}$, then $a_{ii}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$"? Is this the unique sufficient condition?

Comment: @the_candyman No, my claim is that if the  $i$th row of $A$ is zero with the exception of $a_{ii}$, the entry on the main diagonal, then  $i$th column of $A^T$ is zero with the exception of $a_{ii}$. Therefore $a_{ii}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$. Then $a_{ii}$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: finally, if the $i$-th row of $A$ is equal to $a_{ii}{\bf e}_i$, then for sure $a_{ii}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, right?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes! See my edited answer.